# Get text from dynamically created TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamic

I have a button when clicked creates textboxes dynamically:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
         Name.Add(new TextBox());
         System.Drawing.Point locate = new System.Drawing.Point(137, 158 + i * 25);
         (Name[i] as TextBox).Location = locate;
         (Name[i] as TextBox).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 20);
         StartTab.Controls.Add(Name[i] as TextBox);
         }
```

I want to get the text entered in Name[i] convert to a string then set it to labels

Comment: When do you want to do that? In the code that you show, the controls have not even been shown to the user yet, so the user can't have entered anything into them.

Comment: @ newStackExchangeInstance 
modname[i] = Name[i].ToString();
string assessName = modname[i];

Comment: What is the declared type of "modname"?  You need to access the .Text() property of the TextBoxes such as `(Name[i] as TextBox).Text`.  You could try: `(modname[i] as Label).Text = (Name[i] as TextBox).Text`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Control.ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**UPDATED:**

```
TextBox txtName =  (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtNameOfTextbox", true)[0];

if (txtName != null)
{
    return txtName.Text;
}
```

Comment: its says 'does not contain definition for FindControl'

Comment: You are right @I4V, thanks for the warning. Updated my answer. yeeeh can you try this?

Comment: @semihyagcioglu This will work if he assigns a name to his TextBox's, currently his code does not. Also Value is not a property of a Winforms TextBox Text is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type that `Name` is, it looks like a list of some sort. Try using a `List<TextBox>` that way you can just access the `TextBox` properties directly.  Something like this. I am also not sure what Control that `StartTab` is, so I just used a `Panel` for this test code. (you should also be aware that `Name` masks the Form's `Name` property that is why I changed your list to `name`)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<TextBox> name = new List<TextBox>();
    int length = 5;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            name.Add(new TextBox() { Location = new System.Drawing.Point(137, 158 + i * 25), 
                                     Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 20) });
            StartTab.Controls.Add(name[i]);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            StartTab.Controls.Add(new Label() {Location = new System.Drawing.Point(name[i].Location.X + name[i].Width + 20,
                                               name[i].Location.Y), 
                                               Text = name[i].Text, 
                                               AutoSize = true });
        }
    }
}
```